# Require statements needed when something is already attached to a request in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Let's say I have an app in Node with the main elements of the application in a file at the root directory called `app.js`. Now let's say I have a route in `./routes/index.js`.

If some of my middleware in `app.js` attaches handlers to the request, do I need to `require` the library that added that handler when handling the route in `index.js`?

I.e. in `app.js`:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
...

app.use(flash());
```

And in `index.js`:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash'); // ???

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

   res.render('index', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });

});
```

It appears to work without the require statement in `index.js`, but I want to make sure I'm understanding this conceptually. Once something is attached to the request, it stays with the request wherever it goes, right?

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? What happens?

Comment: Whenever you use a middleware in the form `app.use(flash());` it is made available all through each request. What does that mean?
It means you don't need to require that package anywhere as it is made available all through out your app when `index.js` is loaded.

Comment: @raykrow yeah, it works whether including the require statement or not.

Comment: @ John Kennedy appreciate that explanation. It certainly squares with what I'm seeing in testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an express application you create a "tree" so to speak, meaning that wherever you apply middleware any descending route will go through that function. So if we put the middleware at the top of our application all requests will go through that function. You only need to require the middleware wherever you are applying it to the application.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. You only need `require` to get access to exported items from the module. If you don't need to access them (for instance, because something is already accessible as a property on `req`), you don't need the `require`.